# Overcoming the need of having a constructor in the definition of an other constructor

Tags: coq

Most probably I'm trying to achieve something flawed, but I'm running into a need to have a constructor in the definition of another constructor.

### Silly example:

```
Inductive silly_type : Type :=
| constr1 : nat -> silly_type
| constr2 : forall (x : silly_type), (exists n : nat, (x = constr1 n)) -> silly_type.
```

There are two ways how to create elements of `silly_type`, either with natural number and `constr1` or using `constr2` and element of `silly_type` that was created with `constr1`.

The above definition of `silly_type` is not valid in coq, but I do not know how to overcome this in my less silly example.

### Less silly example:

I'm trying to have an inductive type `expr` representing typed expressions.

Let's first start with an inductive type representing types:

```
Inductive type : Type :=
| base_type  : nat -> type
| arrow_type : type -> type -> type
| iso_arrow_type   : type -> type -> type.
```

There are some base types indexed with integers, `arrow_type` representing function between types and `iso_arrow_type` representing invertible functions between types.

Notation:

```
Notation "A --> B" := (arrow_type A B)   (at level 30, right associativity).
Notation "A <-> B" := (iso_arrow_type A B).
```

Type for expressions:

```
Inductive expr : type -> Type :=
| var  : forall (X : type) (n : nat), expr X
| eval : forall {X Y : type} (f : expr (X --> Y)) (x : expr X), expr Y
| inv  : forall {X Y : type}, expr ((X <-> Y) --> (Y <-> X))
| to_fun : forall {X Y : type}, expr ((X <-> Y) --> (X --> Y))
| to_iso : forall {X Y : type} (f : expr (X --> Y)), (is_invertible f) -> expr (Y --> X).
```

You can create an indexed variables of any type with `var`, evaluate a function with `eval`, invert an invertible function with `inv`, cast an invertible function to the actual function with `to_fun` such that you can evaluate it with `eval`.

The problem is with the last constructor `to_iso`. Sometimes, I will know that a function(element of `X --> Y`) is actually invertible and I want some mechanism to cast it to the type `X <-> Y`.

However, to define `is_invertible` I think that I need to use `eval`. This leads me to the problem that the constructor `eval` needs to be in the definition of the constructor `to_iso`.

---

To define `is_invertible`, we first need to define a notion of equality of `expr`:

```
Inductive ExprEq : forall (X : type),  X ->  X -> Prop :=
| expr_eq_refl : forall {X : type}, forall (x : X), ExprEq X x x
| eq_on_values : forall {X Y : type}, forall (f g : (X --> Y)), (forall (x : X), f[x] == g[x]) -> f == g
where 
"x == y" := (ExprEq _ x y) and "f [ x ]" := (eval f x) and "x =/= y" := (not (ExprEq _ x y)).
```

Thus, we have standard reflexivity `x == x` and equality of functions `f==g` can be decided by equality on all elements `f[x]==g[x]`.

Now, we are ready to define `is_invertible`:

```
Definition is_invertible {X Y : type} (f : X --> Y) : Prop := exists g : Y --> X, (forall x, g[f[x]] == x) /\ (forall y, f[g[y]] == y).
```

This definition of `is_invertible` is problematic, it is using `eval`(`f[x] := (eval f x)`). Furthermore, the problem is a bit more complicated. We need to define the type `ExprEq` that already uses `eval` to define its constructors.

### Constrain: keep `expr` decidable

What I really want to preserve is that the equality(`=`) of `expr` is decidable, i.e. being able to prove

```
Lemma eq_expr_dec {X : type} (x y : type) : {x=y} + {x<>y}.
```

I really do not care about decidability of the defined equality `==`, but decidability of `=` is important for me.

Comment: Common wisdom is to avoid mixing syntax and semantics, precisely to avoid the circularity issues you are running into. The way you describe `is_invertible` seems very much semantic, so have you considered not encoding it in the syntax and accepting having partial semantics?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Yes I'm considering that, too. Right now, I'm exploring different ways how to do the thing.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia If I understand you correctly, do you suggest leaving out `is_invertible` from the definition of `to_iso`? And later on, when working with an expression, checking if all uses of `to_iso` are valid?

Comment: That's right! That's what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dependent types to index your constructors. For example

```
Inductive silly_type : nat -> Type :=
| constr1 : nat -> silly_type 0
| constr2 : silly_type 0 -> silly_type 1.
```

So you can only use values produced by constr1 in constr2. This approach should work in general to distinguish values created with different constructors.